# BroadcastReceiver starting service after a period of time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Is there anyway to do it? I've tried using `wait()` and some other methods, but all failed.

Comment: What do you wan't to achieve? We need a bit more information if, you wan't an answer you can actually use.

Comment: @CornflakesDK I have a broadcast receiver which listens for incoming MMS messages and it would start a service, lets say 10 seconds, after the intent "android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED" is received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wither use `AlarmManager` to set an alaram to start your service, or use `Thread.sleep()`.